# Mutiply Inequation for both sides with a variable

Tags: pyomo

I have a question, I need to multiply an inequality both the minimum and the maximum by a binary variable that, if 0, would be rendered inoperative by the "machine" (b1). How do I incorporate that into Pyomo?

[Here's a reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eWIDZ.jpg)

### It's a constraint problem

```
m=4
n=3

#Boiler minimo

boiler_min= [400, 500, 300, 240]

#boiler máximo
boiler_max= [900,700,600,800]

#boiler cost per ton
boiler_ton= [9,7,8,6]

#boiler fixed cost
boiler_fc= [160,200,190,250]

#turbine minimo
turbine_min= [100,400,300]

#turbine máximo
turbine_max= [700,800,600]

#turbine Kwh per ton of stream
turbine_ton= [7,3,6]

#turbine Processing Cost per Ton
turbine_pc = [9,4,6]

modelito= ConcreteModel()

modelito.m = RangeSet(m)
modelito.n = RangeSet(n)

modelito.b = Var(modelito.m, domain=NonNegativeIntegers)
modelito.t = Var(modelito.n, domain=NonNegativeIntegers)

#Variables binarias
modelito.p = Var(modelito.m, domain=Binary)  #binary boiler        
modelito.q= Var(modelito.n, domain=Binary)   #binary turbine

#declare objective
modelito.cost= Objective(expr = (sum(boiler_ton[i-1]*modelito.b[i] for i in  modelito.m) + sum(turbine_pc[j-1]*modelito.t[j] for j in modelito.n) + sum(boiler_fc[i-1]*modelito.p[i] for i in  modelito.m )), sense=minimize)

#Constraints

#modelito.constraint = Constraint(expr= sum((modelito.b[i]<=boiler_max[i-1])>=boiler_min[i-1] for i in modelito.m))


#opción 1
def restriccion(modelito,i):
  if modelito.p==0:
    return Constraint.Skip
  else:
    return ((modelito.b[i]<=boiler_max[i-1])>=boiler_min[i-1])

modelito.constraint = Constraint(modelito.m, rule = restriccion)

def restriccion2(modelito_1,j):
  if modelito.q==0:
    return Constraint.Skip
  else:
    return (modelito.t[j]<=turbine_max[j-1])>=turbine_min[j-1]
modelito.constraint1 = Constraint(modelito.n, rule = restriccion2)

modelito.constraint2 = ConstraintList()

modelito.constraint2.add(sum(turbine_ton[i-1]*modelito.t[i] for i in modelito.n)>=9000)

modelito.pprint()
```

Any suggestion can help me

Comment: Hi, @Coke Verdejo Can you please, say whats the problem? In the posted model, you got a couple of approach problems. In `pyomo` you can't use the `if statement` in a `Var` and expect it to be dynamic. If you write `modelito.b[i]<=boiler_max[i-1]*modelito.p[i]` you're already constraining the `modelito.b[i] Var` to be zero if the commitment variable `modelito.p[i]` is zero, else, `modelito.b[i]` is constrained to be less or equal than `boiler_max[i-1]`. But I don't understand what you want to do

Comment: Also, please note that for further `Pyomo` versions (i don't remember since what versions), chained inequalities are `deprecated` and you need wheter to use the `inequality()` class, or separate it into 2 constraints. Inequality represents the chained inequality like the following `pyomo.inequality(model.a, model.x, model.b)` --> `a<=x<=b`